# Apache Whirr on EC2 with custom AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, apache-whirr

I am trying to launch a cluster of custom AMI images. AMI image is just Ubunutu 12.04 server image from Amazon free tier selection with Java installed (I actually want to create AMI with numpy and scipy). In fact, I created that image by launching the Ubuntu 12.04 instance with whirr and noop as a role. Then I installed Java, and in AWS online Console selected Create Image (EBS AMI). I am using same whirr recipe script I used to launch original ubuntu server with only image-id changed.

Whirr launches the image, it shows up in the console. Then it tries to run InitScript for noop and nothing happens. After 10min it throws exception caused by script running for too long. whirr.log containts record

```
error acquiring SFTPClient() (out of retries - max 7): Invalid packet: indicated length 1349281121 too large
```

I saw this error mentioned in one of the tutorials, suggested solution was to add line

whirr.bootstrap-user=ec2-user

to let JCloud know the username. I know this is the correct username and was used by default anyway. After adding the line, whirr.log shows authentification error, problem with public key.
Finally, when I use 'ubuntu' as user, the error is 
    Dying because - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Here's file I use to launch the cluster

```
whirr.cluster-name=pineapple
whirr.instance-templates=1 noop
whirr.provider=aws-ec2
whirr.identity=${env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
whirr.credential=${env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
whirr.private-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa
whirr.public-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
whirr.env.repo=cdh4
whirr.hardware-id=t1.micro
whirr.image-id=us-east-1/ami-224cda4b
whirr.image-location=us-east-1b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception log will help us to solve your problem.

Also, setting the following may solve your issue.

```
whirr.cluster-user=<Clu>
```